# How can we recognize if $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is supposed to be $\arcsin(x)$ or if it is supposed to signify $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I had a student ask me a question today involving the integral of $\sin^{-1}(x)$. He mistakenly assumed that he could rewrite it as the integral of $\csc(x)$, when instead the question was referring to the inverse sin function. I did not have a good explanation as to why the notation is so similar other than to say that $\csc(x)$ or $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ would be specified. How can we recognize if $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is supposed to be $\arcsin(x)$ or if it is supposed to signify $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$?

I also wondered if issues like this explains why some curricula use $\arcsin(x)$ instead of the power notation, as well as a part of the reason $\sec(x)$, $\csc(x)$, and $\cot(x)$ exist notationally.

Comment: Whenever I see any of the trig functions with a negative one exponent, I always assume "functional inverse" (e.g., $\sin^{-1}x=\arcsin x$) rather than "multiplicative inverse" without further context.  This is the only function group and the only specific exponent that I see in this way.

Comment: $\arcsin$ should really be written as such, or as $\sin^{\circ-1}$ rather than $\sin^{-1}$, to avoid this kind of confusion. Unfortunately, that's not what people do. My guess is the $\sin^{-1}$ notation predates the general $f^{\circ n}$ notation.

Comment: I don't like the notation $\sin^{-1}$ because $\sin$ does not have an inverse: rather, its restriction to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ does. That's one reason to prefer $\arcsin$. Regarding your other question, I think the reason that $\sec$, $\csc$, and $\cot$ are "named" is [historical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#History). In fact, there used to be more trigonometric functions.

Comment: Computer programming languages tend to use `arcsin` or `asin` for the simple reason that superscript $^{-1}$ isn't an ASCII character.

Comment: In my experience, $\sin^{-1}(x)$ exclusively means $\arcsin(x)$.  This never bothered me as a student, but once I started teaching, I had students ask why $\sin^n(x)$ for $n>1$ exclusively means $(\sin(x))^n$, but $n=-1$ exclusively means $\arcsin(x)$.  I still have no response to that.

Comment: I wonder if someone (especially an author) has ever written $\ln^{-1} x$ and if they meant the inverse or the reciprocal of $\ln x.$ I have never seen it. Normally, for reciprocal you would see $(\ln x)^{-1}.$ And for Reciprocal of $\sin$ you would see $(\sin x)^{-1}.$

Comment: *ALWAYS* arcsin.

Comment: This is a good argunent for using $\arcsin(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

It’s just because of tradition (and maybe miscommunication). Just look below:

1.

$$
(\sin \theta)^-1 = \csc \theta, \theta \ne n\pi; n \in \mathbb Z
$$
But
$$
\sin^{-1} \theta = \arcsin \theta, \theta \in [-1, 1]
$$

2.

$$
(\sin \theta)^2 = \sin^2 \theta
$$

3.

$$
(\sin \theta)^{-2} = \csc^2 \theta= \csc (\theta)^2, \theta \ne n\pi; n \in \mathbb Z
$$

4. However in any other function:

$$f^2(x) = f\circ f(x) = f(f(x))$$

$$
y = f^{-1}(x), \text { then } f(y) = x
$$

---

One other reason can be that in past there was no reciprocal of trig functions. All of them were treated as separate functions. But later many of them were abandoned because they could be expressed from other functions. So in past as there was no use of $f^{-1}$ in trig - they just wrote it for inverse instead. Look at the following picture for some of the abandoned trig functions.

[image: trig functions]

Regardless, I suggest: At the start of the class 1 of Trignometry or Function - caution students that the way it is expressed for Trigonometry is completely wrong but we still do it. And when you mean to write reciprocal write it as $(\sin \theta)^{-1}$ and for inverse $\sin^{-1} \theta$